# How to return specific data from a column of a dataframe when a different column value match

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Dataframe with three columns that i recieve from a excel file and create using pandas, so my program needs to order the points column and return a string with the ordered names.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHNJY.png)

so i make the ordering in a list appart from the DataFrame so at the end i have a list with the ordered numbers, what i want to do is using this list to match the Dataframe 'name' column to print the name corresponding to that score  for example print the name of the person with 0 points first and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in function to sort the dataframee.

`df.sort_values(by=['Points'])`

df - dataframe object, Points - name of the points of the column. Once sorted, the dataframe can be printed as usual.

For other parameters that can be used, take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) of the function.